# ffmpeg: concatonate tons of files with different formats

Tags: ffmpeg

Per [HERE](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec), I can concatenate multiple files with different formats.

But the problem is I have tons of, thousands actually, files. So I try to use `ffmpeg.exe -i mylist.txt -filter_complex "[0:a:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map "[outa]" output.mp3`

mylist.txt has the format:

> file file1.wav
>   file flle2.mp3

But it doesn't work. Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Error message:

> Input #0, tty, from 'mylist.txt':
>    Duration: 00:00:00.04, bitrate: 4 kb/s
>      Stream #0:0: Video: ansi, pal8, 640x400, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:a:0]>
>   [1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[outa] matches no streams.

I think I need a means to let ffmpeg read in the whole configuration, or `-filter_complex` part will be still too long for the command line limits.

I found [someone](https://superuser.com/questions/1052177/concatenate-a-list-of-files-with-different-resolutions) have the same question, but it seems not resolved.

Comment: What's the full command you tried?

Comment: @Mulvya I updated my question.